# Noob programmer can't figure out simple issue

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
print name + " do you want to play a game?"
answer = input("To play the game, type either yes or no. ")
if answer == yes:
    print "Great," + name + "lets get started!"
elif answer == no:
    print "Okay, good bye!"

import random

number = random.randint(1,50)
guess = input ("Pick a number between 1 and 50. This number cannot be a decimal. ")
if guess > number:
    print "Your guess is too high!"
elif guess < number:
    print "Your guess is too low!"
while guess != number:
    print "Try again!"
else import random
    number = random.randint(1,50)
if guess == number:
    print "You guessed it!"
    print "Great job."
print "Do you want to play again?"

while answer == yes:
    import random

    number = random.randint(1,50)
    guess = input ("Pick a number between 1 and 50. This number cannot be a decimal. ")
    if guess > number:
        print "Your guess is too high!"
    elif guess < number:
        print "Your guess is too low!"
    while guess != number:
        print "Try again!"
    if guess == number:
        print "You guessed it!"
        print "Great job."
    print "Do you want to play again?
elif answer == no:
    print "Okay. Good game " + name + "!"
    print "Play again soon!"
```

Ok, my first question is why does python not recognize input for the name variable as a string.

The second question is the last elif statement keeps giving me a syntax error. I am not sure why.

The last question is can I loop this code any easier way?

Comment: The syntax highlighting gives away the last problem: you forgot the closing quotation mark, ", on the line above.

Comment: Some notes: 1) Make your titles descriptive. Your current title doesn't tell me anything about your question. 2) If you reference errors or exceptions, copy the full text of it into your question. The text of your syntax error would tell us where it is. 3) Leave out the entire P.S. and thanks. It doesn't add anything to your question, and if you're asking your question correctly, there won't be any hate (except for the worst of people, and your request won't discourage them anyway). 4) Ask only one question in each post. 5) Reduce your code to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2x versions, `input()` takes variable as `integer`, you could use `raw_input()` to take it as string.

So basically change your `input()` to `raw_input()` for taking the data as string.

In Python 3x versions there is no raw_input, there is only input() and it takes the data as string.

Second question;

```
elif guess < number:

    print "Your guess is too low!"

while guess != number:

    print "Try again!"

else import random

    number = random.randint(1,50)
```

This is not a correct syntax, your `else` needs an `if` block above itself. You can't use `else` without an `if` block.If you think for a second, that makes sense.

Your last question is not fit with SO rules.

Comment: `input()` evaluates the input as code; it returns an integer only if an integer is what the user types.  If the user typed something like `"wow"`, it would return a string.

Comment: Specifically, [`input` on Py2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) is equivalent to wrapping the same `raw_input` call in `eval`; it's a source of security and stability bugs, and should almost never be used. If you want to accept arbitrary Python literals from the user without executing entirely arbitrary code, you can `import ast` and do `ast.literal_eval(raw_input(...promptstr...))`, or to accept only `int`, `int(raw_input(...promptstr...))`.